# A powerful IDE for HTML5, CSS3 and JS development

Tags: html, css, web-applications, ide, development-environment

I am looking for an IDE which will support the development of stand-alone HTML5 applications.

Preferably a free one. It must have following features:

**HTML5**

- Syntax highlighting
- Customizable source formatter
- Code navigation (to corresponding CSS and JS files)
- Code completion
- Validation

**CSS3**

- Syntax highlighting
- Customizable source formatter
- Source cleanup (like sorting properties etc.)
- Code completion
- Validation

**JavaScript**

- Syntax highlighting
- Customizable source formatter
- Source cleanup (like sorting functions, adding braces etc.)
- Code navigation
- Code completion
- Validation

Is there any IDE which can all this things?

I tried following IDEs but none of them fulfill all the requirements (I have written some limitations next to each):

WebStorm 5.0.4 (the closest one)

- No source cleanup for CSS especially no auto sorting of properties
- Source formatter for CSS is not configurable enough (I cannot get new line for each selector)

Eclipse 4.2.1 with WDT:

- No source cleanup for CSS
- Source formatter for CSS is not configurable (I cannot get new line for each selector)
- Code navigation from HTML to CSS is not working

Aptana Studio 3:

- Does not support CSS3 ("1.5rem" gets formatted into "1.5 rem", Validation is not working properly)
- Code navigation from HTML to CSS is not working.

Visual Studio 2012

- No source cleanup for CSS
- There is no project type for standalone HTML5 application
- Source formatter for CSS is not configurable enough (I cannot get new line for each selector)
- Code navigation from HTML to CSS is not working

If I am wrong about some limitations then please let me know...

Comment: This does not fit the standard of a stackoverflow question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @John, I am looking for a yes/no type of answer. It is not about which IDE do people like more. I don't see how my question is chatty or open-ended.

Comment: You've listed best IDEs available. I prefer WebStorm. You better do CSS cleanup somewhere else.

Comment: How would 'yes' or 'no' answer your question?

Comment: @robertc Did you even read the question? I can repeat it: "Is there any IDE which can all this things?". Something like "Yes - [IDE name]" or "No, I did some research before and did not find anything better too" would perfectly answer my question.

Comment: Did you even read the FAQ John linked to?  Here is your answer: yes, many.  Here are some valid (though not necessarily appropriate to SO) questions which you could have asked instead: "How do I get Visual Studio 2012 source formatter to add a newline for each selector?"; "How can I get WebStorm 5.0.4 to do source cleanup for CSS (especially no auto sorting of properties)?"

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Sublime Text 2 : http://www.sublimetext.com/2

It's really powerful thanks to his packages you can install developed by the community http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community.

For example, you can sort your CSS using a package called CSS Comb.
You can check your js syntax using a package called JSLinter.
And there's a plenty of others packages available to answer to your requierements.

Comment: Thanks! I already started looking into it. Is there any preconfigured variant of Sublime Text 2? Otherwise it will be much work to find and install all the plugins. For example, for CSS Comb you need PHP to be installed...

Comment: I don't know about a preconfigured version of ST2.. You can find some repositories on github with their configuration (just google it).